# How to build your own MeanJS Docker image?

Tags: node.js, docker, mean-stack

I'm new to Docker and I've been given a task to create a custom container which runs one of our Mean stack apps.

I've created my own simple php container on AWS using https://hub.docker.com/_/php/ , and it works I can access it, but I was just wondering how to do it with the Mean stack.

The application we have here is run locally using [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

I've looked at multiple blogs/tutorials online such as :

- https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/
- https://blog.giantswarm.io/getting-started-with-docker-and-meanjs/

but I still feel lost.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you wish to customise something that exists in docker, you have two issues.

- The changes you make to image you are using now
- The run time changes you want to make on the container, such as ports

My understanding from your question is that you needed to change the image, push it docker.hub and use it in the future. Here is how I see it.

- start the current container
- Make some changes, eg. Add new files, add data to the mongoldb.
- Save the changes into a new image. see (docker commit --help)
- Now you have a customised image.